# How to sum elements from a Key List using ListMultimap from Guava

Tags: java, arrays, guava, multimap

## **Example:**

I want to **sum** the elements inside every key, which is basically an ArrayList of elements "double numbers".The *Guava ArrayListMultimap* is declared in this way:

```
ListMultimap <String, Double> multimap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
```

and displayed like this "3 keys of ArrayList":

```
HH_0=[0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1], 
HH_1=[0.1,0.2], 
HH_2=[0.1]
```

The summation should be stored in an array or any simple structure like this output:

```
array_sum=[1.1,0.3,0,1]
```

the actual size of *multimap* is **8** and not **3** because if any key has more than one value in its arraylist, means the key is duplicate and that's reason of using *multimap* of *Guava* , it can store duplicated keys with multiple (different or same) values in an *ArrayList* with the contrary in case of a simple *Hashmap.*

**My essay:**
I extracted the keys in *array_Str* of *Strings* to compare with. We suppose the length of the wanted *array_sum[ ]*  is already initiated with 3:

```
double sum = 0.0;
String array_Str = {"HH_0","HH_1","HH_2"};

       for (int i = 0; i < array_sum.length; i++) {
           for (Entry<String, Double> entry : multimap.entries())  {
               
               
           if( entry.getKey().equals(array_sum[i])) {
               
               sum=sum+ entry.getValue();
           }
               
           }
           array_sum[i]=sum;   
       }
```

Any guidance is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 streams to simplify just a little:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_str.length; i++) {
  array_sum[i] = multimap.get(array_str[i]).stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).sum();
}
```

Comment: thanks but it caused an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to String"

Comment: That sounds like you have a typo in copying this code, e.g. in your usage of `array_str` vs. `array_sum`.

Comment: so it means i have to parse a string to a double? because i'm trying to compare the strings from *array_str* with the keys from *multimap* if it matched i add element from the arraylist and sort it in array_sim

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't have to parse a string to a double, you just have a mixup in your code.

Comment: Ah for sure, i did fix it now it's all working thanks a lot.